# Passing matching value from view to html in django

Tags: python, django

- So i have tried various ways from passing the value from view to html page in django.
- Depending upon the user logged in by matching the `email` I want to retrieve some information of the user in the html.
- In few I have faced error such as
  `AttributeError at /user_profile'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'`
- For the above method in `views.py` i was using

```
# user profile
def user_profile(request):
    user_data = UserProfile.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).values()
    context = {
        'name' : user_data.name,
        'emailID' : user_data.emailID,
        'phone' : user_data.phone,
        'college_name' : user_data.college_name,
        'branch' : user_data.branch
    }
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', context)
```

- My UserProfile model looks like this

```
# User profile
class UserProfile (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    emailID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

- And I was using the `{{context.college_name}}}` in `html` code.
- If I just return the `JsonResponse` in the `views.py` I get the output properly as seen below.

```
{"Matched data" : [{"id": 4, "name":"sample", "emailID":"lav@test.com", "phone": "1234567890", "college_name": "Dummy", "branch": "CS"}]}
```

- But while passing it to html either I am getting some error or the values are just not bein displayed.
- Passing the dictionary is resulting in empty dictionary being passed.

```
# user profile
def user_profile(request):
    user_data = UserProfile.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).values()
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {"Matched data": list(user_data)})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter used in the query will give you the Queryset. That's why you are not getting name attribute as its a Queryset not a single user. You just need a single output. Change below code

```
user_data = UserProfile.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).values()
```

to

```
user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
```

This will give you only one user in user_data with email ID mentioned in get parameter.

Also pass the context in html as below :

```
return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'context' : context})
```

Comment: I have changed as you told 
```def user_profile(request):
    user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
    context = {
        'name' : user_data.name,
        'emailID' : user_data.emailID,
        'phone' : user_data.phone,
        'college_name' : user_data.college_name,
        'branch' : user_data.branch
    }
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', context)```
But still no values are being showed in the html part. I am using ```{{ context.branch }} ```

Comment: pass the data as     return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {'context' : context})... 
I have updated the answer with the same.

Answer (score 0):

You make a relationship between the user and `UserProfile` in a very bad manner. Since the `UserProfile` will belong to a user and there would only be one for each user, you should be using a `OneToOneField` to make a [One-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) between them.

```
from django.conf import settings

class UserProfile (models.Model):
    # Remove name user has first_name and last_name fields.
    # remove email id. User has that field.
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now to access a user's profile (It should be created first) one can simply write:

```
profile = request.user.profile # profile is the related_name we have set in the model
```

One does not even need to pass this in the context (request and user are added to the context automatically) as one can directly access it in the template like:

```
{{ request.user.profile.college_name }} # College name of the profile
```

Comment: I am using the google auth so depending upon the logged in user, for e.g. if the user has logged in for the very first time under ```Profile``` he can add up his details, where further ```emailID``` is going to be a unique value. If the user has already entered all the details it will be fetched from the ```UserProfile``` table. 
So depending upon the user logged in I am going to store the value or the user can update his details.

Comment: @LavSharma And how does that prevent you from adding a model with a `OneToOneField` with user. Your way of indicating a relationship between the user and UserProfile is not very useful for the database (Also it leads to you being unable to maintain any integrity in your tables). A relationship **should** be indicated by a Foreign Key in the database.